# Removing indexes from an associative array

Tags: arrays, associative-array

I have an array like this

```
   Array
(
    [0] => array('projectname', 'total_requests'),array('Project3' , 1),
    [1] => array('RTI' , 1),
    [2] => array('STAEP' , 3),
    [3] => 
)
```

I just want to remove `[0]=>`,`[1]=>`,`[2]=>`,`[3]=>` without converting this into string is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Array can either have an index or be an associative array. This means that the array index is a string. Both methods require the index to be unique allowing the information to be accessed outside of the array.

In short: in order for you to still use it as an array it has to have the index.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You are right the data is just like this

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'array('RTI' , 1),' (length=17)
  1 => string 'array('STAEP' , 3),' (length=19)
  2 => string ')' (length=1)
```

But i want data in this format

```
Array(array('projectname', 'total_requests'),
     array('Project3' , 1),
     array('RTI' , 1),
     array('STAEP' , 3),

)
```

without "0=>string"
is it possible.

Comment: Are you just wanting the arrays to be displayed onto the screen without the indexes?

Answer (score 0):

Basically my data is like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [projectname] => Project3
            [total_requests] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [projectname] => RTI
            [total_requests] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [projectname] => STAEP
            [total_requests] => 3
        )

)
```

And i want to change that data into this format using string

```
$mystring=" array(array('projectname', 'total_requests'),";
foreach($result as $value)
{
    $mystring.= 'array('.'\''.$value['projectname'].'\''.' , '.$value['total_requests']."),";
}
 $mystring.=')';
```

I got the desired result but it is in String i want this result in array

```
array(
        array('projectname', 'total_requests'),
        array('Project3', 1),
        array('RTI', 1),
        array('STAEP', 3),
    ),
```